# parsing urls from windows batch file

Tags: vbscript, batch-file

I have a text file (myurls.txt) whose contents are a list of URLs as follow:

```
Slides_1:   http://linux.koolsolutions.com/svn/ProjectA/tags/REL-1.0
Exercise_1: http://linux.koolsolutions.com/svn/Linux/tags/REL-1.0

Slides_2:   http://linux.koolsolutions.com/svn/oldproject/ProjectB/tags/REL-2.0
Exercise_2: http://linux.koolsolutions.com/svn/ProjectB/tags/REL-1.0

Exercise_3: http://linux.koolsolutions.com/svn/BlueBook/ProjectA/tags/REL-1.0
```

Now I want to parse this text file in a for loop such that after each iteration (for e.g. take the first url from the above file) I have the following information into different variables:

```
%i% = REL-1.0
%j% = http://linux.koolsolutions.com/svn/ProjectA
%k% = http://linux.koolsolutions.com/svn/ProjectA/tags/REL-1.0
```

After some experiment I have the following code but it only works (kind of) if the URLs have same number of slashes:

```
@echo off
set FILE=myurls.txt
FOR /F "tokens=2-9 delims=/ " %%i in (%FILE%) do (
@REM <do something with variables i, j and k.>
)
```

Obviously, I need to make it more flexible so that it can handle arbitrary url length. I am fine with other solutions like for e.g. using Windows Script Host/VBscript as long as it can run with a default Windows XP/7 installation. In other words, I know I can use awk, grep, sed, python, etc. for Windows and get the job done but I don't want the users to have to install anything besides a standard windows installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this might be what you are looking for, though I am not absolutely sure what your rules are for identifying the project.

It uses the FOR `~pnx` modifiers to parse parts of a path. Use `HELP FOR` from the command line for more info. It uses `\..\..` to get to the grand-parent "directory", and `\` is prepended to make the "path" absolute.

The result converts `/` and `//` into `\`, so variable search and replace is used to restore the proper slash delimiters, and a substring operation is used to strip off the leading slash. Use `HELP SET` from the command line for more information on search and replace and substring operations.

Delayed expansion is used because it needs to expand a variable that was set within the same block of code.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "file=myurls.txt"
for /f "tokens=1*" %%A in (%file%) do (
  for /f "delims=" %%C in ("\%%B\..\..") do (
    set "project=%%~pnxC"
    set "project=!project:~1!"
    set "project=!project:\=/!"
    set "project=!project:http:/=http://!"
    echo header  = %%A
    echo url     = %%B
    echo project = !project!
    echo release = %%~nxB
    echo(
  )
)
```

Here are the results for your sample data:

```
header  = Slides_1:
url     = http://linux.koolsolutions.com/svn/ProjectA/tags/REL-1.0
project = http://linux.koolsolutions.com/svn/ProjectA
release = REL-1.0

header  = Exercise_1:
url     = http://linux.koolsolutions.com/svn/ProjectA/tags/REL-1.0
project = http://linux.koolsolutions.com/svn/ProjectA
release = REL-1.0

header  = Slides_2:
url     = http://linux.koolsolutions.com/svn/oldproject/ProjectB/tags/REL-2.0
project = http://linux.koolsolutions.com/svn/oldproject/ProjectB
release = REL-2.0

header  = Exercise_2:
url     = http://linux.koolsolutions.com/svn/ProjectB/tags/REL-1.0
project = http://linux.koolsolutions.com/svn/ProjectB
release = REL-1.0

header  = Exercise_3:
url     = http://linux.koolsolutions.com/svn/BlueBook/ProjectA/tags/REL-1.0
project = http://linux.koolsolutions.com/svn/BlueBook/ProjectA
release = REL-1.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Actually there is no rule for identify project. In fact the URLs might not even have the name Project in them. For example, a URL can simply be: http://linux.koolsolutions.com/svn/LinuxMaterial/tags/REL-1.0. The only form is that the each URL has header (like Slides_N or Exercise_N) and ends with /tags/REL-X.Y.

Comment: @modest - Well that is a rule :-) Thankfully it is also compatible with the rule that I implemented. I strip off the last 2 path components to get the project, which would correspond with "/tags/REL-X.Y". It looks to me like your question has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

:: First seperate into Label, URI type, and internet path
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=:" %%x in (URLs.txt) do (
  echo.

  :: Take the Label
  for /f %%a in ("%%x") do set LabelNam=%%a

  :: Assemble Release URL
  set ReleaseURL=http:%%z

  :: Delayed variable expansion is required just for 'z'
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    :: Take Release URL Path
    set z=%%z

    :: Extract the Release
    for /f "tokens=2" %%b in ("!z:/tags/= !") do set Release=%%b

    :: Split the Internet Path at the '/''s and call ':getURL'
    call :getURL %%y !z:/= !

    :: Output the information 
    echo       Label = !LabelNam!
    echo     Release = !Release!
    echo         URL = !URL!
    echo Release URL = !ReleaseURL!
  :: End variable expansion
  endlocal
)
goto :eof


:getURL
  :: Get URL type
  set URL=%1:/
  :: shift all arguments one to the left
  shift

  :URLloop
    :: Assemble URL
    set URL=%URL%/%1
    shift
  :: If we haven't fount 'tags' yet, loop
  if "%1" neq "tags" goto :URLloop

goto :eof
```

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to post, but I got very distracted by an extremely odd error. if you add another colon delimited comment above `:: Extract the Release` I get a `The system cannot find the drive specified.` error. Just a pair of colons will do it. But replace the `::`'s with `REM`, and it acts just fine. I played with it and got different errors. It's just so **BIZZARE**.  And I still haven't figured out what's going on.

Comment: The **BIZZARE** effect comes from primary/secondary label lines inside parenthesis [SO: windows batch file with goto command not working](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4006006/463115)

Comment: @jeb - Ach, I should of known! I remember `::` breaking my code before by causing the code act like it was outside the parenthesis. Thanks for reminding me. ^_^

Comment: @jeb - Say, I also had trouble doing this: `for /f "tokens=* delims=/" %%x in ("http://somesite.com/path/whatever") do echo %%x` because it would always just echo the entire URL, and not split it up. But it works if I specify the tokens.  Do you know if that's just a bug in `for`?

Comment: It's not a bug, `tokens=*` is interpreted as _ONE_ token with the complete content, you have to declare each token at the `tokens=` option to be able to access them later, but you are allowed to skip some tokens, like `tokens=1,4,7,*`

Comment: @jeb - I just double checked and your right.  I was thinking that I'd successfully used that method to split up a line and send all the tokens to a :lable that just used `%1` and `shift` to read in an unknown number of tokens.  Well, it can't help that I haven't gotten any sleep in the past 48 hours. :(  I must have done an `...in ("%var:/= %") do ...` equivalent instead.

Answer (score 1):

OK, my shortest and most understandable, though least commented solution:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=: " %%x in (URLs.txt) do (
  set LabelNam=%%x
  set ReleaseURL=%%y:%%z
  for /f "tokens=1-31 delims=/" %%a in ("%%y:%%z") do call :getURL %%a %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f %%g %%h %%i %%j %%k %%l %%m %%n %%o %%p %%q %%r %%s %%t %%u %%v
  echo.
  echo       Label = %LabelNam%
  echo     Release = %Release%
  echo         URL = %URL%
  echo Release URL = %ReleaseURL%
)
goto :eof

:getURL
  set URL=%1/
  shift
  :URLloop
    set URL=%URL%/%1
    shift
  if "%1" neq "tags" goto :URLloop
  Set Release=%2
goto :eof
```