# ) was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file, parentheses

I am using the following code to check for files before renaming, and if not, check for another file to display a message.

```
SET offline=1
IF EXIST %webroot%\%sitename%\app_offline.htm.scheduled (
    call :displayMsg "Taking %sitename% website offline"
    ::                =================================
    REN %webroot%\%sitename%\app_offline.htm.scheduled app_offline.htm
) ELSE (
    IF EXIST %webroot%\%sitename%\app_offline.htm (
        call :displayMsg "%sitename% website is already offline"
        ::                =====================================
    )
)
```

But the following is being returned

```
D:\Company\DeploymentFolder>SET offline=1
) was unexpected at this time.

D:\Company\DeploymentFolder>        )
```

I cannot see a problem with my parenthesis? Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `::` comments with a `REM` and it should work.
You could use `::` but then you need to know the *two lines* rule of [Labels in parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4006006/463115)

Comment: Thank you very much, that's right. Do you know why this is the case. I have been using '::' for months now, but made some changes to my script today which has caused it to start to fail. What I don't understand is the changes I made weren't relating to this section of the script?

Comment: You should follow the link. It will fail, as you have a single label just in front of the closing parenthesis.