# What does :: (double colon) mean in DOS batch files?

Tags: batch-file

I found this program [web.archive.org: http://baiyunmanor.com/blog/work/get-current-date-time-in-dos-batch-file/](https://web.archive.org/web/20140225075758/http://baiyunmanor.com/blog/work/get-current-date-time-in-dos-batch-file/)

```
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::
:: This uses Windows Scripting Host to set variables
:: to the current date/time/day/day_number
:: for Win9x/ME/NT/W2K/XP etc
:: Thanks go to Todd Vargo for his scripting
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
@echo off
set TmpFile=”%temp%.\tmp.vbs”
echo> %TmpFile% n=Now
echo>>%TmpFile% With WScript
echo>>%TmpFile% .Echo “set year=” + CStr(Year(n))
echo>>%TmpFile% .Echo “set yr=” + Right(Year(n),2)
...
cscript //nologo “%temp%.\tmp.vbs” > “%temp%.\tmp.bat”
call “%temp%.\tmp.bat”
...
echo date F [ddmmyy] [%day%%month%%yr%]
:: datetime.bat
```

But I don't know what does the line

```
:: datetime.bat
```

at the end mean?

Comment: Beware of using :: as rem in batch programs that are called by Task Scheduler. When writting and testing a batch program it worked as expected from the command prompt, but when running the same thing from Task Scheduler it throws error:
'if' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

`::` is a label (inaccurately also known as *comment label*) can be, in practice, considered a comment just as `REM` is, because it is an "un-goto-able" label.

There are some **differences** between `REM` and `::`, though. The main ones are:

- With `ECHO ON` a `REM` line is shown but not a line commented with `::`
- A `::` can execute a line end caret (that is, a `^` at the end of a line starting with `::` makes the next line **also** a comment):

  ```
   :: This is a comment^
   echo but watch out because this line is a comment too
  ```
- Labels and `::` have a special logic and can cause problems in parentheses blocks - take care when using them inside `(` `)`. Example:

  ```
   for %%D in (hi) do (
       echo Before...
       :: My comment
       :: Some other comment
       echo After...
   )
  ```

  Outputs:

  ```
   Before ...
   The system cannot find the drive specified.
   After...
  ```

Comment: When you cite that `::` "is also called _comment label_" you should include a link to the _official_ source where you got that cite; otherwise you are contributing to spread _popular beliefs_ that may be wrong.

Comment: The most important difference is the special logic inside of parenthesis blocks. Would be great if you could add a resource for more information on that.

Comment: The special handling in blocks is described at [SO:goto command not working](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4006006/463115) and more about [SO:Which comment style should I use in batch files?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12408045/463115)

Comment: Wow, I used :: in a for loop and it took me a whole day to reach this post. The behavior of double colon in () in my case seemed undetermined. If it is just by itself in for(), it either crashes execution or says "...cannot find specified drive" (to that effect, different language) while "chdir" clearly showed my "cd" worked.

Answer (score 69):

A line that start in double colon represent an *invalid label* that is ignored by the command processor, so it *may* be used to insert a comment. For reasons that can't be traced, many people use `::` to insert comments in Batch files, but you must be aware that there are several pitfalls in its use that are described in the link given in Koterpillar's answer. It seems that the first use of `::` instead of `REM` command was with the purpose to speed up the execution of Batch files in slow machines (ie: floppy disks), but that reason is not a valid justification for the use of double colon since many years ago.

Any line that contain an invalid label will be ignored by the command processor and you may use practically any special character to generate an invalid label. For example:

```
@echo off

:~ This is a comment
:` This is a comment
:! This is a comment
:@ This is a comment
:# This is a comment
:$ This is a comment
:% This is a comment
:^ This is a comment
:& This is a comment
:* This is a comment
:( This is a comment
:) This is a comment
:_ This is a comment
:- This is a comment
:+ This is a comment
:= This is a comment
:{ This is a comment
:} This is a comment
:[ This is a comment
:] This is a comment
:| This is a comment
:\ This is a comment
:: This is a comment
:; This is a comment
:" This is a comment
:' This is a comment
:< This is a comment
:> This is a comment
:, This is a comment
:. This is a comment
:? This is a comment
:/ This is a comment

echo OK
```

In other words: if you want to insert a comment and you want not to use `REM` command (although I can't think of any reason to do so), you have 32 possible character combinations to do so. Why you should use precisely this one: `::`? Just because some old programs written 35 years ago did it?

Comment: At all you are right (as nearly always), but I can't see why you made this list? `"~``!@#$%%*()_-{}[]\'.?/^&|<>` are legal labels, only `+=,;:<space>` can't be used as labels.

Comment: @jeb: I just want that the reader realize that the use of `::` to insert "comments" have not reasonable basis.

Comment: Since you can't think of reasons I'll give you two: **readability** (the `::` stands out as non-alphabetic in what's mostly alphabetic characters in a batch script ... and if you come from C++ where `//` is a single line comment, `::` kinda makes sense for the same purpose) and **saving space** (if you've ever hit the upper size limit - somewhere beyond 60 kB - with a script you'll appreciate being able to save some bytes ... and yes, there are also good reasons for such big monolithic scripts).

Comment: @0xC0000022L: It seems that you didn't read my post nor my comment. If you want **readability** and you come from C++, then `://` makes _much more sense_ to insert a single line comment! From this point of view, why don't use `:'` like in VBScript, or `:#` like in PowerShell and several other script languages, or `:--` like in SQL, or `:<--` like in HTML, etc... In other words: if you want to insert a comment and you have 32 possible character combinations to choose from, why you should use precisely this one: `::`? The selection of `::` have not _reasonable=acceptable=logical_ reasons

Comment: @Aacini: I did read it and it *prompted* me to comment. And out of your five alternatives **all** require more movement of my fingers than `::` and even worse, three out of the five use more than two characters. Now while that's a *logical* explanation, I can't help with "reasonable" or "acceptable", because these are entirely subjective. But out of those alternatives `://` would be the most acceptable to me, if I didn't also have the option to use `::`.

Comment: `REM` errors out on comments like `REM /?a=1` ("`1 was unexpected at this time.`") whereas `::` seems to handle them just fine.

Comment: @Aacini: this was informative. I was only aware of ::, but I can see value in some of those other choices. Like 0xC0000022L was suggesting :// makes sense for someone already familiar with C++. The greatest reason I can see to stay with :: is because some editors with syntax highlighting already see :: as a comment when editing cmd scripts and don't recognize the others. I could use something else, but I'd be making things more difficult if I did. This was still informative.

Answer (score 20):

A line starting with a colon is a label which you can jump to with `goto`:

```
goto end
:end
```

A line starting with a double colon is a label, except you can't, even accidentally, jump to it:

```
goto :end REM this doesn't work
::end
```

Thus, double colon is used to comment lines out.

Source: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/comments.php

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned by [acdcjunior](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1850609/acdcjunior) *Labels and `::` have a special logic and can cause problems in parenthesis blocks*

Here are couple of samples

Sample 1

```
IF 1==1 (
  ::
)
```

Output of sample 1

```
) was unexpected at this time.
```

Sample 2

```
IF 1==1 (
  ::
  ::
)
```

Output of sample 2

```
The system cannot find the drive specified.
```

Answer (score 2):

The colon (:) is a label marker and can be used for got instructions.

Some people use : as a comment too so a double colon is simply a stylistic REM statement

Answer (score 1):

If you use the traditional `REM` command to comment out a line in a DOS batch script then any output redirection in the comment is still done. For example, consider this script:

```
echo 1 > a.txt
rem echo 2 > b.txt
echo 3 > c.txt
```

This script will truncate `b.txt` even though the line appears to be "commented out".

Using an invalid label prefix like the double colon will disable any redirection.

Comment: Sorry that's wrong, at least since MS-DOS6.22. `REM` is even *stronger* than label comments. The parser stops parsing a line if `REM` is used, but not for labels

Comment: @jeb: I just tried on FreeCOM and `rem > a` does create the file `a`. So at least FreeDOS does do redirection for the `rem` command. Later today I can test on my MS-DOS machine.

Comment: @jeb: Just remembered I can try it [on pcjs](https://www.pcjs.org/machines/pcx86/ibm/5170/vga/cdrom/). Load the MS-DOS 6.22 diskette, restart, exit setup, do `rem > a`, then `dir a` lists the file created from this redirection.

Comment: As said, it works on MS-DOS 6.22 (just tested in virtual box), but since then `REM` doesn't redirect anymore. The question was about `cmd.exe`. Once upon a time: Your answer *was* correct :-)

Comment: @jeb: The question title includes the term "DOS batch files". And it is tagged #dos. Forgive me for giving a reply concerning DOS. (I'm fairly sure my answer is also correct for MS-DOS 7.xx as bundled with MS Windows, so the "since then" isn't entirely accurate either. Perhaps NT's `cmd.exe` does work as you suggest.)

Comment: You are right, I'm wrong, even with Window98 the REM redirection still works (also tested). But I edited the question to be more accurate, as the sample code expected at least Windows NT

Comment: @jeb: It doesn't expect "at least Windows NT", it is intended "for Win9x/ME/NT/W2K/XP". In MS Windows 4.x (the 95/98/Me line) batch files are actually interpreted by DOS's `command.com` and, as you tested, this shell does do redirection on `rem` lines. So even if there is no reason to prefer `::` over `rem` for MSW NT with `cmd.exe` then the question still includes "Win9x/ME" where there is this difference.