# What does this construct ":------------------------" mean in a bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am doing some batch programming and found this useful script for elevating permissions

https://sites.google.com/site/eneerge/scripts/batchgotadmin

I am fairly well versed with bat file programming but have never seen the construct on line 4

```
:: BatchGotAdmin
:-------------------------------------
```

What is it. I hope its not an alternate mechanism to specify comments

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does :: (double colon) mean in DOS batch files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16632524/what-does-double-colon-mean-in-dos-batch-files)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically it's a label.  Anything that begins with a `:` is a label.  You could probably do a `goto -----------------------------------` if you really wanted to.  But as you guessed (and others answered) it's just being used a comment in this case.  Just like any label can be used as a comment.

Answer (score 3):

To borrow your wording:
Its an alternate mechanism to specify comments.

You basically answered your own question.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a comment with a bunch of dashes in it. It has no special meaning to the interpreter, but it looks like a line across the page, so it may serve as a way of (visually!) dividing the script up into sections.