# what is the comment (batch file) in Win& and pipe NOT work

Tags: windows, batch-file, pipe

I just change a Win7 Computer, but I found many old batch files not work in Win7.

Most serious problem is program crash/stop/error when run at comment line (I use ":" for comment).
What is the comment line in Win7?
Any efficient method to correct them? there are many comment in my batch file.

Besides, I have use the "pipe" to block the stdin input

```
command1

 echo off | command2

 command3
```

They work properly in WinXP, but NOT work in Win7.

Comment: Maybe you should show us the batch file, which is [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You have to use `::` or `rem` to comment a line.

Comment: A single colon has *never* been a comment character.  It starts a label, which is something entirely different.

Comment: A line that start in double colon is _not_ a comment either. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16632524/what-does-double-colon-mean-in-dos-batch-files/16639875#16639875).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to write comment (or **rem**ark) in a batch file is to use the `rem` command.

Quoting the command's "help":

> Records comments (remarks) in a batch file or CONFIG.SYS.
>
> REM [comment]

For example:

```
rem This is a comment.
```