# Vlookup logic to create a folder for moving a report

Tags: batch-file, scripting, command

I have two files say Report.csv Reference.csv

I want to write a Script will reference the Report-ID in the report file names and cross-reference with Reference file data to determine the folder location to move the report.

For eg: Report.csv

```
R-00001.csv
```

Data in Reference.csv as below:

```
ReportID CompanyName
R-00001  BB Trust
R-00002  AA Trust
R-00003  ZZ Trust
R-00004  Canada Inc.
```

Here in the above, we could see that file name of Report.csv & the first cell value in the Reference.csv is same.

After lookup, the R-00001.csv file needs to be moved to "BB Trust" folder

Likewise, for each of the Report file, same procedure needs to be followed

Please help, it would simplify my work

```
  echo off
  :: Gets the filenames to textfile
  dir /b "C:\Users\Reports\" > 
  reportnames.txt
  :: Compare two files to look for 
  the matching ReportID and get the 
  Companyname value from 
  Reference.csv & create a folder in 
  that name and move the report 
  files to that corresponding folder

  for /f "tokens=1" %%i in 
  (Reportnames.txt) do
  @findstr "%%i," Reference.csv >nul 
  & If errorlevel 0 if not
  errorlevel 1 (for /f "tokens=2" 
  %%m in ('findstr /i /L "%%i," 
  Reference.csv') do ( cd 
  C:\Users\Archive\ & mkdir 
  %%m))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your description is somewhat confusing and the example code does not match the problem description, so I chose to follow the code.

It has no case to *first* create the `Reportnames.txt` file from a `dir /B` listing, and *then* process such a file... You may directly process the list of filenames via a standard `for` command.

The simplest and most direct way of "lookup logic" to find the matching CompanyName for a ReportId is via an [array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990) (although you may know it as an [associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array)).

Finally, it is not a good idea to use [the `::` trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16632524/what-does-double-colon-mean-in-dos-batch-files/) to insert comments instead of `rem` commands (no matter how many examples you may see with such a trick).

```
@echo off

rem Next line is required to correctly process array elements in a FOR loop
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Load the associative array from Reference.csv file
for /F "skip=1 tokens=1*" %%a in (Reference.csv) do set "CompanyName[%%a]=%%b"
rem Previous FOR is equivalent to these lines:
rem set "CompanyName[R-00001]=BB Trust"
rem set "CompanyName[R-00002]=AA Trust"    etc...

rem Process the filenames
for %%a in (C:\Users\Reports\*.*) do (

   rem Get the matching CompanyName for the ReportId
   set "folder=!CompanyName[%%~Na]!"

   if not exist "C:\Users\Archive\!folder!" md "C:\Users\Archive\!folder!"
   move "%%a" "C:\Users\Archive\!folder!"

)
```

If you have any doubt about a command, you may review the command description entering it with the `/?` parameter; for example: `set /?`