# Batch File IF Statement evaluation problems

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Please excuse me if I have made an obvious mistake.

The batch file I have been working on is to prepare some folders (D:\Backups_pc and sub folders Backup_Main and Backup_Copy).   Depending upon them existing or not on the D: drive when attached.

The first time the batch file runs it does create the folders and then Robocopies the necessary folders and files into 'Backup_Main'.  The second and subsequent times the batch file is executed on the same D drive it should copy the Backup_Main to Backup_Copy and Robocopy updates the Backup_Main.

It doesn't do that but always GOES TO 'KDTFirstRun'.

I have tried IF EXIST D:\Backups_pc\Backup_Copy to evaluate presence of folders and that did similar so in this version I tried to check everything first and store it, thinking that something may be buffered or not evaluated correctly so try to preset it (so to speak).   It hasn't worked so I am at a loss.  I can't see white spaces in variable definitions, math or whatever to cause the problem or am I blind?

Some help would be very much appreciated.  Thank you.
Phil.

```
@ECHO off 
SETLOCAL

::   Batchfile to do two types of backup

::   Attempt using variables defined here and set to ZERO

SET /A RootB=0
SET /A MainB=0
SET /A CopyB=0

::  Set the Variables based on folders being in place or not

IF EXIST "D:\Backups_pc\" SET /A RootB=1
IF EXIST "D:\Backups_pc\Backup_Main\"  SET /A MainB=1
IF EXIST "D:\Backups_pc\Backup_Copy\" SET /A CopyB=1

:: Diagnostics Echo reports

ECHO R = %RootB%
ECHO M = %MainB%
ECHO C = %CopyB%

SET /A KDTCheck = %RootB% + %MainB% + %CopyB%

ECHO KDTCheck is %KDTCheck%
PAUSE

IF /I KDTCheck EQU 3 GOTO KDTUPdate
IF /I KDTCHeck EQU 2 GOTO KDTFolderError
IF /I KDTCheck EQU 1 GOTO KDTFolderError
IF /I KDTCheck EQU 0 GOTO KDTFirstRun

:KDTFirstRun

ECHO Initialising System and Preparing Backup_Copy.

:: Create the necessary folders, I know I could get smarter but lets get the IF stuff working first.

MD D:\Backups_pc
MD D:\Backups_pc\Backup_Main
MD D:\Backups_pc\Backup_Copy

ECHO Folders created on D Drive
ECHO Backing Up Backup_Main

::  Robocopy a lot of folders

ECHO Backup_Main has been updated with latest data from your computer.  
GOTO KDTend


:KDTUpdate
ECHO Updating Backup_Copy.
::  Copy the Backup_Main to Backup_Copy
ECHO In KDTUPdateMain Updating Backup_Main

:: Re run the Robocopy stuff that was done in KDTFirstRun

ECHO Backup_Main has been updated with latest data from your computer.  

GOTO KDTend

:KDTFolderError

:: Some limited diagnostics to view.
ECHO There is a problem with the Backup Folders on Drive D.
ECHO R = %RootB%
ECHO M = %MainB%
ECHO C = %CopyB%
ECHO KDTCheck is %KDTCheck%

:KDTend
ENDLOCAL
PAUSE
@ECHO ON
```

Comment: Sincere thanks paxdiablo all advice taken on board.   It just shows how some online 'Tutorials' can mislead you.   That is where I got the :: for REM from.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
IF /I KDTCheck EQU 3 GOTO KDTUPdate
```

You need `%` variable markers around your variables:

```
IF %KDTCheck% EQU 3 GOTO KDTUPdate
```

Without those, it's comparing the *string* `KDTCheck` rather than the variable content. And, because all the `if` statements are failing, it's just dropping through to the code below.

You'll notice I've also removed the `/I`, there's little sense doing a case-insensitive comparison on digits.

---

In short, that comparison code snippet would be better off written as:

```
REM Go to specific action or error part if invalid setup.

IF %KDTCheck% EQU 3 GOTO KDTUpdate
IF %KDTCheck% EQU 0 GOTO KDTFirstRun
GOTO KDTFolderError

:KDTFirstRun
```

---

As an aside, it's not a good idea to use `::` for comments. That *actually* is a label-type construct and will cause you much angst and teeth-gnashing if you use it in the wrong place, such as:

```
if %optn%==1 (
    :: Option 1 chosen
    goto option1_code
)
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16632524/what-does-double-colon-mean-in-dos-batch-files) for further information on that.