# Unexpected "The system cannot find the drive specified." in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've got a problem with a batch file (Windows 7 x64). I've managed to reduce it to the following (there are two empty comment lines; it doesn't seem to matter whether there's an actual comment):

```
@echo off

if /i [%1]==[] (
    echo A
    ::
    ::
    echo B
)
```

Putting this in a batch file and then running it with no parameters produces the following output:

```
A
The system cannot find the drive specified.
B
```

Deleting one of the `::` lines, or deleting the surrounding `if`, *fixes* things so you get the expected output:

```
A
B
```

What's going on here? Why is it looking for a drive?

**Edit**

Thanks for the responses for far. So my question really boils down to this:

> What are the rules for determining whether `::` means "start of comment" or "drive letter colon"?

Perhaps it's easier to just switch back to `REM` for adding comments so there's no scope for ambiguity, but I do find the `::` style easier to read.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's an obscoure effect in batch code blocks.

In a code block a label in one line requires always a secondary line with quite different syntax rules (for a *secondary* line).
[SO: goto command not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4006006/463115)

The secondary line must be a command or simple label, but not a parenthesis nor a double colon nor an internal command appended with a parenthesis.

MC ND explained that the `:` is used here like a normal drive letter, that's really true!
But only in the secondary line and even you can suppress the error by a `subst :: C:\`, the line is handled like a label (You can't start anything).

```
subst :: C:\
(
:label
::\windows\system32\calc.exe
)
```

And the secondary line accepts `&` even when the line is a label.

Failing samples

```
(
:Label at the end fails
)

(
:label
  ( 
    echo new Block fails
  )
echo ...
)

(
:label
:: Double colon fails
)

(
:label
echo( fails also, as now a file named "echo(" is searched for execution
)
```

And now working ones

```
(
::Works
:with a "normal" label in the second line
)

(
:But this label! & echo This will not echo'd
:but & echo You can see this !
)

(
:label
echo or a simple command works too
)
```

Sometimes `::` is used as a [comment style](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12408045/463115), this can cause problems inside blocks, if you don't care about the secondary line.

**Edit: To answer your second question**

> What are the rules for determining whether :: means "start of comment"
>   or "drive letter colon"?

The first `::` is always a comment or label, in the next line it's always a `drive letter colon`.

Comment: Right. The error is in the second `::`, and the reason what you stated. First line is a label and second is expected to be a valid command, and as :: can be considered valid, it is executed. And, yes, you can start something using `start ::\windows\system32\calc.exe`. As commented before, not all parts of the system handle it.

Answer (score 7):

`::` is a valid drive. Just as `c:` or `d:` but the letter is `:`

So, your lines are trying to change from the current drive to drive `::`

Example: try `subst :: c:\` and then `dir ::\`

Comment: +1, but `::` is not a 'fully satisfying' drive, `subst` without parameters doesn't display this.

Comment: @Endoro, `mountvol :: /L` and `mountvol c: /L` . For me both are the same volume. But yes, not all tools in the system work with it.

Comment: But why it works when you insert an `echo x` between the two `::` lines?

Comment: +1 I've tested it and it really suppress the syntax error in the second line